# why google map geometry conflict with drawing library

Tags: google-maps-api-3

When I use both library drawing and geometry at same page, geometry decodePath function not work. how to fix this problem?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=falselibraries=drawing"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry"></script>

google.maps.geometry.encoding.encodePath(latlngs);

google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(encodedPolyline);
```

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle or link to some code that isn't working?

Answer (score 6):

You are not including it correctly.

You are including the API twice, once with the drawing library (and that is incorrect), and once with the geometry library.

Instead of:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=falselibraries=drawing"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry"></script>
```

Try the [documented way](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/libraries) [To request multiple libraries, separate them with a comma:]

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=drawing,geometry"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, but I found problem is that, decodePath function only convert encodedPath to string not to MVCArray.

Wrong if like this

```
Polyline.setPath = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(encodedPolyline);
```

Should like this

```
Polyline.setPath = toMVCArray_function(encodedPolyline);
```