# How to load the google maps api and the places library at a later time?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

I have a Website with a CMS and several widgets that need Google Maps but only one that needs the place library. On some pages only one widget appears and there are also some pages with the two widgets. So what I wanna know is - is there a way to load the places library separately if the google maps api already is loaded?

Here is a fiddle with what I tried, but it would need the google js api as an extra request and besides there occures an error in the console: `Uncaught TypeError: google.maps.__gjsload__ is not a function`
So there has to be a better way.

https://jsfiddle.net/0bh83v87/

To check if google maps has been loaded this statement can be used:

```
if (typeof google === 'object' && typeof google.maps === 'object') {...}
```

But is there a way to load the places library afterwards? It's because most of the time I won't need it but if the two widgets are on the same page it's necessary.

***Update:***
I tested the script loading with and without the places library on an empty site and it shows that there are 6 Requests anyway and the size difference is just 1kB - even with Network Throttling there is no significant performance difference so the easiest thing to do is to import the places library just everywhere...

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34757535/how-can-i-use-google-maps-api-and-places-library?rq=1) if it can help you :)

Comment: Thx! But that's not the point. It's easy to load the library from the start. The question was how to load the library separately because I thought it would cause a performance lag but it doesn't. ;)